# rails helper inside collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I have a simple helper

```
 def get_ecr_name(name)
   name.present? ? :name : :ip
 end
```

want to use in collection select

```
=f.collection_select(:ecr_id,  current_user.ecrs, :id, get_ecr_name(@ecr.name), :prompt => 'Select ECR')
```

but problem if ecr haven't name other select options are empty[image]

Comment: What happens when you change to `get_ecr_name(name,ip)` and call as `get_ecr_name(@ecr.name,@ecr.ip)`?

Comment: @Pavan it return to me list of ip's,my goal is when no name show ip in select menu

Answer (score 0):

Since `collection_select` will call your helper method once with `@ecr.name`(where `name` is present), it returns `:name` and hence `name` method is being called. One way to overcome the situation is to create an another variable of an array object in your controller like so:

```
@ecrs = current_user.ecrs.map{|ecr| (ecr.name = ecr.name.present? ? ecr.name : ecr.ip); ecr } # returns a temporary modified ecrs array.
```

then use it in your view:

```
= f.collection_select(:ecr_id,  @ecrs, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Select ECR')
```

Answer (score 0):

Those blank select option contains id so

for id you write another helper

```
def get_ecr_id(id,name)
   return id  if name.present?
end
```

then re-write

```
=f.collection_select(:ecr_id,  current_user.ecrs, get_ecr_id(@ecr.id,@ecr.name), get_ecr_name(@ecr.name), :prompt => 'Select ECR')
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for it, there is a option for options_from_collection_for_select

```
<%= f.select :ecr_id, options_from_collection_for_select(get_ecr_name(@ecr)).name, 'id', 'name') %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help.I redo to `f.select` based on your anwers

```
    =f.select('ecr_id', current_user.ecrs.collect {|p|[get_ecr_name(p.name,p.ip),p.id] }, { prompt: 'Select Ecr' })
```